# What is the phenomenon I'm observing here?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, moments

I was looking at the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) and wanted to make a quick simulation to see the results. I made a quick program simulating 1 Billion "games" and the average of the gain (over several runs) was around 30/40. Quite low.

My guess would be that the theoretical "Infinite" gain that could be made out of this game is out of reach for only 1 Billion games. Is this correct?

My next step was to try to see how a variation of the paradox would behave. My variation is basically putting a limit to the number of flips allowed and see what the results could be. As an example if the maximum number was 3, the game would become "flip a coin, if head you win 1, if tail flip again. If head you win 2, if tail flip again. If head you win 4, if tail you win 0". For a low number of maximum flips I was expecting to reach the theoretical results (5 max flip -> 5 max gain), while for higher numbers I was expecting a more and more chaotic result.

This is indeed what happens. Up to 28 flips or so the gain grows quite linearly, then it becomes more chaotic.

[image: Avg]

So far so good, I think. Now I got more curious to know if it was somehow possible to quantify this chaotic behavior and my (quite limited) knowledge in statistics made me think of considering the standard deviation of the results. My Expectation here would have been to see a growing standard deviation. This is instead what I got:

[image]

While initially there is a slow and reasonable increase of the standard deviation, then it completely blows up and becomes meaningless as well.

At this point I'm a bit lost for what statistical tools can be used to described the results I'm seeing here.

So my questions would be:

- Why is the standard deviation so chaotic?
- What are tools can explain the results?
- What are some better ways to quantify the randomness of the results as the maximum number of flips increases?

Bonus question:

Is there a theoretical way to calculate the number of total games I should play for a specific number of maximum flips in order to get a "reasonable" (as in what the theory would predict) result with a specific confidence?

Comment: See this paper  [The time resolution of the St Petersburg paradox](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsta.2011.0065).

Answer (score 1):

No actual sample of games will be ever infinite. Even if you perform a billion games and compute the average.

The outcome of the games will follow some distribution with $\lim_{X \to \infty} P(x>X) = 0$.

The infinity relates to the expectation of the *distribution* being unbounded (but the average of a sample from this distribution will not have an infinite value).

---

Below is a computation of the cumulative probability distribution of the average win of a sample up to size 30 games (darkest = sample size 1, lightest = sample size 30).

I can imagine that there is some limiting distribution for this (it should be some [alpha stable distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) and it appears like a Lévy distribution) and one might try to compute this, but I guess that this illustration already shows sufficiently that it it not weird that some computation with a large sample might result in a finite or relatively low average amount of profit. The infinity of the expectation is only in the extremely long tail, but to get this tail you have a very tiny probability.

[image: example]

In the above graph $k$, depicted on the x-axis, is the average sum of money won in $n$ games (where we changed $n$ from $0$ to $30$).

For example. If we play two games, then

- the probability to win on average 1 is when we win 1 in each of the games (probability 0.5*0.5 = 0.25)
- the probability to win on average 1.5 is when we win 1 in one game and 2 in the other game (probability 0.5*0.25 + 0.25*0.5 = 0.25)
- the cumulative probability to win on average 1.5 or less is the probability to win either 1.5 or 1 and is the sum of the previous two results. This cumulative probability is what is shown along the y-axis in the graph.

R-code

```r
n = 30     # sample size
n2 = 10000 # range of money for which we define and compute the probability distribution
           # for sample size n=30 we end up with the range n2/n^2
 

### compute/define the initial distribution for a single game
k = 1:n2
p = k*0  
for (i in k) {
  ### if the value i is a power of 2
  ### then assign 1/i as probability
  if (log(i,2) %% 1 == 0) {
    p[i] = 1/i/2
  }
}

#### function to compute convolution
#### with this we can compute the distribution of the win in multiple games
fconvolve = function(p1,p2) {
  p_out = p1*0
  p_out[1] = 0
  for (i in 2:length(p1)) {
      p_out[i] = sum(p1[1:(i-1)]*rev(p2[1:(i-1)]))
  }
  return(p_out)
}

### plot defined distribution
pn = p
plot(k,cumsum(pn), type ='l', xlim = c(0,n2/n^2), ylim = c(0,1))

### compute and plot distribution of average amount of win for multiple games
for (l in 1:n) {
    pn = fconvolve(pn,p)
    lines(k/(l+1),cumsum(pn), col = rgb(l/n/2,l/n/2,l/n/2))
}
```

Comment: Much of this answer seems likely to confuse readers. What do you mean by a "sample"? It cannot possibly be the standard meaning (of a subset of a population or process), for then in what sense would these subsets "follow some distribution"? If a sample really does refer to a sequence of coin flips and you bound its length at 30, then some single real number represents the "average win," so in light of that what does your plot show?  What does "k" represent?